# What is the use of ".at()" in JavaScript?And does it work in normal JavaScript (browser JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
 array.at()
```

Or is it for node.js or JavaScript!

Comment: It's very new and not part of the official ECMAScript specification yet. Production NodeJS environments typically lag-behind V8's ECMAScript support by a few years, so I don't recommend using `at()` in code that will run in NodeJS for a while. At least it is trivial to polyfill though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [pretty new proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method). The idea behind it is:

> A TC39 proposal to add an .at() method to all the basic indexable classes (Array, String, TypedArray)
>
> For many years, programmers have asked for the ability to do "negative indexing" of JS Arrays, like you can do with Python. That is, asking for the ability to write `arr[-1]` instead of `arr[arr.length-1]`, where negative numbers count backwards from the last element.
>
> Unfortunately, JS's language design makes this impossible. The [] syntax is not specific to Arrays and Strings; it applies to all objects. Referring to a value by index, like `arr[1]`, actually just refers to the property of the object with the key "1", which is something that any object can have. So `arr[-1]` already "works" in today's code, but it returns the value of the "-1" property of the object, rather than returning an index counting back from the end.
>
> This proposal instead adopts a more common approach, and suggests adding a `.at()` method to Array, String, and TypedArray, which takes an integer value and returns the item at that index, with the negative-number semantics as described above.

So `somethingIndexed.at(n)` is essentially the same as `somethingIndexed[n]` - except that `n` can be negative.

`.at(-1)` is equivalent to `somethingIndexed[somethingIndexed.length - 1]`.

`.at(-2)` is equivalent to `somethingIndexed[somethingIndexed.length - 2]`.

And so on.

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
console.log(arr.at(-1) === arr[arr.length - 1]);
```

But it's quite a new proposal. Eventually, it'll be integrated into all modern environments (including Node and browsers), but since it's so new (and not even stage 4 yet), you should not count on it being supported yet. Only use it in production code if you include [a polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method#polyfill).